Question about Dataset/Dataframe mapPartitions iterator
I am running Spark 3.5.0 with Scala 2.12 and had a question about mapPartition. I am creating a mutable list inside the mapPartitions and inserting items inside the iterator. When I try to get the items after the iterating over all the items in the partition, the list is empty. Does anyone know if this expected? Here is contrived example of the code:
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder

val encoder = ExpressionEncoder(df.schema)
df.mapPartitions(it => {
    val list = mutable.ListBuffer[Row]()
    val result = it.map(row => {
        list += row
        row
    })
    println(s"list.size: ${list.size}")
    result
})(encoder).show()


I read the section on RDDs and closures in the Spark documentation and it all makes sense but in my case I am declaring the List inside the anonymous function passed to the mapPartitions API which is, as I understand it, is serialized on the driver JVM and deserialized on the executor JVM so I do not think it explains the issue that I am seeing.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-

Found this post and it looks like the problem was Scala's lazy evaluation of the iterator.
Apache Spark mapPartition strange behavior (lazy evaluation?)
If I change the code to get a list from the iterator, I get the expected results.
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder

val encoder = ExpressionEncoder(df.schema)
df.mapPartitions(it => {
    val list = mutable.ListBuffer[Row]()
    val rowList = it.toList
    val result = rowList.map(row => {
        list += row
        row
    })
    println(s"list.size: ${list.size}")
    result.iterator
})(encoder).show()

This works but I wonder if there are any disadvantages to doing it this? There is additional memory used used to construct the list for example.
